# Cannot modify rows in phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.1

Tags: phpmyadmin

Has anyone experienced this before? There is no "Edit", "Copy", "Delete" (see image) on certain tables, but it's not missing in other tables. I am sure it's not a problem with scrollbars.

[image]

Comment: `lubrication_point_data` is most likely a [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)), especially since the first shown field is an external key.

Comment: It says on top: "This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." what does this mean?

Comment: the first 4 columns are supposed to be the unique identificator, I guess I will just have to manually run an SQL query to modify the data. I just thought this is an error or something.

Comment: Modification is by definition impossible if there's no guaranteed uniqueness amongst rows, usually achieved with a primary key. Did you read the link on 'views' in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, correct. 
I don't have much experience with views so maybe this is the time to read more about it. Thanks for the link.